# Error al sobreescribir un txt

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un servidor web en raspberry pi. Tengo que generar un archivo .txt, esto lo hago con php, en mi maquina loca de windows funciona pero cuando lo ejecuto dentro del servidor es raspberry pi no se sobrescribe. Tengo mi código de php así

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$file1 = 'data.txt';
$file2 = 'semaforos2.txt';
 $semaforo = $_POST['dataString1'];
 $color = $_POST['dataString2'];

if (isset($data)) {

$fp = fopen($file1, 'wb');
$fp2 = fopen($file2, 'wb');
if (!$fp = fopen($file1, "wb") ) {
     echo "No se ha podido abrir el archivo";
}else{
    fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($semaforo));
    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($color));
    fclose($fp);
    chmod($file1, 0777);


    fwrite($fp2, utf8_decode($semaforo));
    fwrite($fp2, "_");
    fwrite($fp2, utf8_decode($color));
    fclose($fp2);
    chmod($file2, 0777);
     echo 'Se han guardado correctamente la información en el txt!';
}

}else {
    echo 'No hay datos que guardar!';
}
?>
```

ya he intentado todo lo que busque por Internet la ruta completa, cambie de código y nada. Pensé que pudiera ser un problema con el lenguaje pero cuando hice lo mismo ahora en py, pero de igual manera cuando ejecuto en php la función 
shell_exec, ocurre lo mismo y no lo sobrescribe. ¿A que se debe eso? alguien que me ayude

Comment: ¿Puedes poner cómo lo hiciste en python? De PHP no sé mucho. En todo caso sospecho que pueda ser un tema de permisos y propietario. Quizás el fichero ya existe (resultado de alguna ejecución previa desde un usuario diferente, tal vez root) y ahora no puedes sobreescribirlo por ser otro usuario.

Comment: ¿Verificaste que tengan las mismas versiones de python o PHP?

Comment: si, estoy usando la misma versión de PHP, y pues ya verifique eso que mencionas @abulafia, no se vino a la mente antes, y si era ese el motivo, me sirvio tu comentario